# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. error: invalid dimen

Tags: java, android

Please Help, Cant figure out how to fix this problem I'm having. These are all the information I could give to you:
my **activity_main.xml**:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

and **dimen.xml**:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">activityhorizontalmargin</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">activityverticalmargin</dimen>
```

**Error log**:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  C:\Users\James\MyApplications\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:431: error: invalid dimen.
  C:\Users\James\MyApplications\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:432: error: invalid dimen.

  Command: C:\Users\James\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\84132278bf8a6c162bc0b3eae2e1efaf\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          C:\Users\James\MyApplications\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
          C:\Users\James\MyApplications\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2
  Output:  C:\Users\James\MyApplications\app\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml:4:5-80: AAPT: error: invalid dimen.

  C:\Users\James\MyApplications\app\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml:3:5-76: AAPT: error: invalid dimen.

  Command: C:\Users\James\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\84132278bf8a6c162bc0b3eae2e1efaf\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          C:\Users\James\MyApplications\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
          C:\Users\James\MyApplications\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect values in **dimen.xml**:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">activityhorizontalmargin</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">activityverticalmargin</dimen>
```

it should be something like this:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">10dp</dimen>
```

Please be noted that dimen is the abbreviation of **dimension**.

More details about it can be read at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension

Comment: Thank you. I fixed my dimen.

Comment: @walockdeathBringer: You're very welcome ;). Happy coding!